# Does GSON or Jackson support a way to extract an array of objects as a stream from a huge JSON document?

Tags: json, gson, streaming

My requirement is to read a huge JSON document which is something like below. However, I'm not interested in certain parts of the document, but only in an array of objects which I would like to deserialize and persist as entities. I'm currently using Gson library and my intention is not to load the entire array into memory, but parse them as a stream one by one.

My JSON document looks like below:

```
{
  "header":{
            ..........
            ..........
   },
   "data": [{},{},{}.......]
  "trailer":{
   }
}
```

assuming that the above JSON represents an object called Document

```
public class Documemt{
    private Header header;
    private Data[] data;
    private Trailer trailer;
}
```

What I'm interested in is Data[]

I started doing as follows

```
InputStream is = Sample.class.getResourceAsStream("/SampleJSON.json");
JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
reader.beginObject();
while(reader.hasNext()){

    //At this point, I'm having issues.
    gson.fromJson(reader,Document.class); //This will load the entire document into memory. which I do not want.
}
reader.endObject();
```

Is there a way to skip Header and Trailer, and create the Data[] object as a stream.

something like

```
 if token == header || token==trailer then
      skip
 else
     Stream<Data> data = jsonReader.read
```

Any pointers or examples for such a requirement.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, if my approach is correct, but I achieved the results as follows

```
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    InputStream is = Sample.class.getResourceAsStream("/SampleJSON.json");
    JsonReader reader = new JsonReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    reader.beginObject();
    while(reader.hasNext()){

        String tokenName = reader.nextName();
        if("header".equals(tokenName) || "trailer".equals(tokenName)){

            reader.skipValue();
            continue;
        }
        reader.beginArray();
        while(reader.hasNext()){
            Data data = gson.fromJson(reader, Data.class);
            System.out.println(data);
            count++;
        }
        reader.endArray();
    }
    reader.endObject();
    System.out.println("Count ->"+count);
```

Is there any flaw in my solution ? Are there better alternatives to this approach ?

Comment: That's a great solution.

Answer (score 0):

You are partially on a right track but there is a way more easier way to do this.

Just declare `DTO` class that holds only the `Data[]`, like:

```
public class DataOnlyDocument {
    private Data[] data;
}
```

Then your `Reader` can be just:

```
Reader r = new InputStreamReader(getClass()
                    .getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/SampleJSON.json"));
```

And `Gson` will happily use that reader by:

```
DataOnlyDocument dod = gson.fromJson(r, DataOnlyDocument.class);
```